# Java pagination and jquery data table

Tags: java, ajax, pagination, datatables

i am currently using data table for pagination in my spring boot web application project. i am performing pagination on the front end using data table

however i have new requirement for back end pagination and i thought that it will return a page if i do it using java and thus i will no longer be able to use data table. i am also using ajax to retrieve the data.

can I use data table with server side pagination in java or how can i do this?

Comment: Did you try to use spring-data and spring-data-rest? I mean `Page<Entity>` and `RestDataRepository` annotation?

Comment: ok i guess that will do it for the back end <now how to handle this front end wise